# Unit Testing and Coding Design

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, design-patterns

In a lot of TDD tutorials I see code like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething(string Data)
    {
      if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Data))
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
}


[Test]
public DoSomething_NullParameter_ThrowsException()
{
   var logic = MyClass();

   Assert.Throws<NullReferenceException>(() => logic.DoSomething(null));
}
```

This all makes sense but at some point you are going to get to the class that actually uses MyClass and you want to test that the exception is handled:

```
public class EntryPointClass
{
  public void DoIt(string Data)
  {
     var logicClass = new MyClass();

     try
     {
        logicClass.DoSomething(Data);
     }
     catch(NullReferenceException ex)
     {

     }
  }
}

[Test]
public DoIt_NullParameter_IsHandled()
{
  var logic = new EntryPointClass()

  try
  {
    logic.DoIt(null);
  }
  catch
  {
    Assert.Fail();
  }
}
```

So why not put the try/catch in MyClass in the first place rather than throwing the exception and have the test that test's for null in the MyClass unit test class and not in the EntryPointClass unit test class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, your exception handling will look like this:

```
public class EntryPointClass
{
  Logger _logfile;
  // ...
  public void DoIt(string Data)
  {
     var logicClass = new MyClass();

     try
     {
        logicClass.DoSomething(Data);
     }
     catch(NullReferenceException ex)
     {
         _logfile.WriteLine("null reference exception occured in method 'DoIt'");
     }
  }
}
```

(The `Logger` is just an example for a resource you need for proper exception handling not available at the place where `MyClass` lives. You could also add the display of a message box here or something like that.)

At the level of `MyClass`, you typically don't have the appropriate tools available for proper exception handling (and you don't want to add them there to keep the class decoupled from, for example, a specific logging mechanism).

Note that this design decision is independent from doing TDD. If you want your class `MyClass` actually catching the exceptions by itself, you have to write your tests differently, that is right. But that is only a good idea if catching the exceptions does not block your automatic tests. Try, for example, to write a good unit test for `MyClass` when `MyClass` shows a hardcoded warning dialog by itself.

Of course, the example above shows that unit testing `EntryPointClass` may get harder in reality when you first need something like a logger to get things working. In general, you can attack this problem by providing the logger at constrcution time utilizing an ILogger interface which allows the logger to be replaced by mock. Or in this simple case, it may be enough not to initialize the logger for your unit tests at all and code it like this:

```
 public class EntryPointClass 
 {
      // ....
      catch(NullReferenceException ex)
      {
          if(_logfile!=null)
              _logfile.WriteLine("null reference exception occured in method 'DoIt'");
      }    
      // ....
 }
```

Comment: Why not have an event in MyClass to handle errors and when an error occurs raise the event?

Comment: @Steve Jobs: that is also a possible solution to keep classes decoupled, but why do you want to make things more complicated than necessary? Exceptions are *the* standard mechanism if errors can not be handled in the place where they occur; building your own event-mechanism for that is just like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If for example you have a List<int> and you do a check to see if its empty. Would you throw a exception or would you raise a friendly event?

Comment: @Steve Gates (AKA Steve Jobs): that depends. Having a list as a function parameter, I typically try to code it in a way where it works for an arbitrary size of n elements, dealing with n=0 not differently from n>0, so no error handling is needed at all. If the case n=0 is a clear violation of the input specification of the function, I would normally throw an exception. Using an event for error signalling is error prone, since the caller could easily forget to subscribe to that event. But that are just "rules of thumb", in the contect of a real application things may look different.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions indicate *exceptional* situation for your code (see MSDN guidelines on [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx)). If argument null is exceptional for `DoSomething`, then throwing it makes perfect sense regardless of *what* and *how* will use that class later. The is part worth highlighting from [Exception Throwing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030.aspx) section is describing it precisely:

> Do report execution failures by throwing exceptions. If a member cannot successfully do what it is designed to do, that should be considered an **execution failure and an exception should be thrown**.

Not to mention, at the time of writing `DoSomething` you might not know what code will use it (in fact you shouldn't event know, nor care).

As a result, if exception throwing is part of code contract - it should be tested, and it should be tested as part of `DoSomething` tests.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not put the try/catch in MyClass in the first place...

Exceptions are for decoupling the error detection and the error handling. If the error cannot be handled (in all cases) locally in MyClass, then You should throw an exception.

This allows a local error detection (MyClass) and an error handling by whoever catches the exception.

---

The test in `EntryPointClass` tests, if the method DoIt is null-safe. It has little to do with its use of MyClass.

In other words: The test in `EntryPointClass` does not and (for code stability and encapsulation issues) should not rely on the fact that `MyClass` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests test units of work

Write one test that tests an exception is thrown then write your code to that spec and watch the test pass (this is your first example)

Then write your code that deals with the exception (if possible) if this does then the test should take no account of that exception as you have handled it and you should measure that the output is expected from that method.

If you cannot handle the exception you should omit the catch step (unless you are logging at this stage) and let it go up the stack in this case you again assert that the method expects an exception.

You never put a try catch in your test code you only assert that an exception is or is not thrown.

As you are testing correct function of your class.

Comment: Surely you need to test somewhere that you have a try/catch block so you know that the app will not crash

Comment: Massively edited this answer because i wasn't clear enough hope this helps

Comment: So you're saying stick and try/catch in but not actually write any tests for it?

Comment: I am saying if you have used a try/catch block and dealt with the exceptional circumstance there must be an outcome to that method which is now valid, you should test for that, the test deals with what you expect to have happened, the exception being thrown is expected so you have must now deal with it, you must test the code that deals with it either by testing something was called or by testing the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually testing two very different conditions:

1. Test that MyClass throws an exception when the argument is invalid
2. Test how EntryPointClass, as a user of MyClass, deals with the exception thrown by MyClass